# Intellij Idea Setting For Editor Scroll

Tags: intellij-idea

In eclipse, the bottom right corner of each file has a "scroll arrow" so you can scroll down one line at a time by clicking it.  It looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know if that is something that can be enabled in Idea?  I haven't been able to find it yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any UI element for this, but there are keyboard shortcuts:

- Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> (I think it's this)
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>

This scrolls up or down (respectively) one line without moving the caret.

Answer (score 0):

It works with `fn` + ↑ Or `fn` + ↓ key for me on Mac. It scrolls up/down one page at a time. Moves the caret as well, not sure if you were looking for something like this.